# PoA throughput with multiple nodes

Tags: parity, poa

Will it be faster for my system, in terms of number of transactions per second, if my network has a lot of nodes?
Does the number of nodes in PoA is related to the throughput?

Particularly I am interested in making a PoA network with Parity, using the AuthorityRound engine.

How does the AuthorityRound engine work for parity? Any resources to check?
Should a transaction be validated by the majority of the validators defined in the chain specs file?